# Saving Web Audio API output to local file in Ionic

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm developing an app using the Ionic Framework. Part of the app is to record audio using the microphone, filter out a range of frequencies, and then playback that sound through the speakers / earphones.

I have that part working using this code

```
function ListenButtonPressed() 
{           
        context = new (window.AudioContext||window.webkitAudioContext);
        navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia ||
                                  navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                                  navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                                  navigator.msGetUserMedia);
        navigator.getUserMedia(
                            {audio:true},
                            SetupFilters,
                            function(e) {
                                alert("error getting user media " + e);
                            });
}

function SetupFilters(stream)
{       
    input = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    volume = context.createGain();

    volume.gain.value = 10;

    lowPass = context.createBiquadFilter(); 
    lowPass.type = 'lowpass';
    lowPass.frequency.value = 25;       

    highPass = context.createBiquadFilter(); 
    highPass.type = 'highpass';
    highPass.frequency.value = 425;     

    input.connect(lowPass);
    input.connect(highPass);
    input.connect(volume);

    highPass.connect(context.destination);
    lowPass.connect(context.destination);       
    volume.connect(context.destination);

    alert("recording started successfully");   
}
```

Now, I'd like another button that records that output of the filters, and saves it as a file in the phones storage system.

I've tried using [RecorderJS](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs) and used [this RecorderJS integration](https://github.com/cwilso/AudioRecorder) in an ionic app, but to no avail.

They work fine in regular browsers, but since it generates a download link instead of just storing the file, they're not much use for a mobile app.

Any suggestions for how to store the file locally, or to use a different approach for filtering out frequencies that allows for file storage are welcome.

Comment: Have you tried using the `File` API to download the file from the generated link by `RecorderJS` and then save it locally?

Answer (score 1):

Got it working, so posting my solution anybody else has this issue.

Download RecorderJS from the git repo in the question, and add [the File plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) to your project.

Change the Recorder.setupDownload function to

```
Recorder.setupDownload = function(blob, filename)
{
try
{     
  window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 1024*1024, function(filesystem) {
        if(filesystem)
        {
            alert("got file system");
            try
            {
                var src = blob; //3-5mb blob from previously retrieved file
                var starttime = Date.now();
                filesystem.root.getFile("NEWFILE.WAV", { 'create': true }, 
                function (fileEntry) 
                {
                  fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) 
                  {
                      fileWriter.onwriteend = function (event) 
                      {
                        alert(Date.now()-starttime); //usually 3-6 seconds lockup
                      };
                      fileWriter.write(src);
                  }, 
                  function (fail) 
                  { 
                    alert("failed saving"+fail); 
                  });
                });
            }
            catch(e)
            {
              alert(e.message);
            }


        }
    });

}
catch(e)
{
  alert(e.message);
}

}
```

This line was added to the bottom of my 'SetupFilters' function

```
 audioRecorder = new Recorder( input );
```

I've buttons that trigger these StartRecording and StopRecording functions

```
function stopRec()
{
    highPass.disconnect();
    lowPass.disconnect();
    volume.disconnect();

    audioRecorder.stop();    
    audioRecorder.getBuffers( gotBuffers );
}
function startRec()
{
    audioRecorder.clear();
    audioRecorder.record();
}
```

Put these functions in the same class as the start and stop recording functions. I'm not 100% sure on what they do as I'm still learning Javascript, but they were taken from the RecorderJS integration linked in the question.

```
function saveAudio() {
    audioRecorder.exportWAV( doneEncoding );    
}

function gotBuffers( buffers ) {            
    audioRecorder.exportWAV( doneEncoding );
}

function doneEncoding( blob ) {
    Recorder.setupDownload( blob, "myRecording" + ((recIndex<10)?"0":"") + recIndex + ".wav" );
    recIndex++;
}
```

After all this, a WAV file is being saved to the phones storage.